# Trying to align two columns in a specific way using HTML within a Wordpress Widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget

.::Edit::.

Fixed Broken Images.

--

I've been trying to align this for a few days now, and I simply don't have the know how to accomplish it.  I photoshopped what I am trying to get this table to look like, but when I try to create a table, I either end up with borders, or an unwanted background.

I'm essentially trying to create what is shown in the following images.

Any help is so very much appreciated it!

This is what it currently looks like

http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z21/therealnrm/hours1.jpg

This is what it looks like in Wordpress Widget Text/HTML

[i193.photobucket.com/albums/z21/therealnrm/hours2.jpg](http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z21/therealnrm/hours2.jpg)

This is what I want it to look like.

http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z21/therealnrm/hours3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, I am not able to comment, can you post the code of the table. Moreover all your images look same.

Here is your code for the footer section...

```
<p>
    <strong>Lunch</strong>
    <div class="flex_column av_one_fourth first  el_before_av_one_half">Tuesday-Friday</div>
<div class="flex_column av_one_fourth el_after_av_one_fourth">11:30AM-2PM</div>
</p>
&nbsp;
<p>
    <strong>Dinner</strong>
    <div class="flex_column av_one_fourth first  el_before_av_one_half">Monday</div>
    <div class="flex_column av_one_fourth el_after_av_one_fourth">5:30 - 9:30 PM</div>

    <div class="flex_column av_one_fourth first  el_before_av_one_half">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="flex_column av_one_fourth el_after_av_one_fourth">5:30 - 9:30 PM</div>
</p>
```

Just repeat the two div sets and fill your day & timing. It will look great.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Won't be using that host for images again.

There isn't really code for the table.  Or a table at all for that matter.

I have used align left and right on the same line, but that isn't the result I was looking for.  And attempted to float left and center, but I'm not sure if that's what I need either.

Comment: can you post your website url so that i can find out the reason for your issue in an easier way?